# Change Background of UIButton ios

Tags: ios

When a user clicks on UIButton, it will display a UIActionSheet letting the user to choose from the options:

1) Take a picture from camera

2) Picture from gallery photos.

If for example, he chooses to pick a picture from gallery photos, when he selects an image and returns to the view, the background image of the UIButton should change.

Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Set Image on Button instead of button text:

```
[yourButton setImage:pickedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Set Background Image on Button:

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:pickedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: i set the UIButton in StoryBoard and i add it's backgroudn from storyboard and when i click on the button and choose a picture and return to view , it is possible to change it's background programatically using the code?

Comment: look at the I Like IOS answer.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
  IBOutlet  UIButton  *yourButton;
}

-(IBAction)changevalues:(id)sender;


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self logAllFilters];
}
- (void)loadPhoto:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *pickerC =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerC animated:YES completion:nil];
}



    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        UIImage *gotImage =
        [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [yourButton setBackgroundImage:gotImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```